# Return sql row as key,value

Tags: c#, sql, dictionary

Is there a way that I can return an SQL row with the format of

```
Dictionary <Key,Value> [] d;
```

So that I can access rows as such...

```
Dictionary<string,value> [] sqlrows = new Dictionary<string,value> [];
```

And

```
int row = 1;
string colname = "id";

object value = sqlrow[row][colname];
```

Comment: Anything is possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Nothing. Not sure if there is a solution for this, which is why I am asking. Dunno if I have to try and write my own code to do this or if there is already a solution... Which is why I am asking. Smart Ass.

Comment: I want something simple that does not require me to iterate through the list of returned columns for each row.  result[rownum][colname] ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LINQ is a good solution too why not using that?

Answer (score 0):

A DataTable has very similar format as your end result.

```
 DataTable dt = *fill datatable here*;
 int row = 1;
 string colname = "id";
 object value = dt.Rows[row][colname];
```

There are plenty of articles on how to fill a DataTable easily from SQL.

If you insist on it being an array of Dictionaries you will have to manually build it up yourself. Use a SqlDataReader to enumerate over each SQL row. For each row you will create a dictionary and add the available column names and values. Then add each dictionary (row) to the dictionary array.